# how to cast other types of key values inside json object other than string to string in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a json object where i want to visualize the keys and key values with  `ListView.builder` :

```
class Items {
  Map<String, dynamic> getItems() {
    String jsonData = '{ "item1": true,"item2": "value2","item3": "value3"}';

    Map<String, dynamic> data = jsonDecode(jsonData);
    return data;
  }
}

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Map<String, dynamic> data = Items().getItems();
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: data.keys.length,
        itemBuilder: (c, index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(
              "Value " + data.values.toList()[index],
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            subtitle: Text(
              "Key " + data.keys.toList()[index],
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And i have inisde the json object inside key `item1` a `boolean` value. And so i get the error `type 'bool' is not a subtype of type 'String'` .

So i wonder how i can show all types of values (not just `boolean`) aside from `String` from the json object inside the `ListView.builder` without getting the error.

Comment: Why not use `data.values.toList()[index].toString();`?

Comment: That worked, i don't know why i didn't thought of that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `data.values.toList()[index].toString();`